# Symfony2.3 - trying to add google authentication with HWIOAuthBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

For the user login I'm trying to add google authentication.

I configured HWIOAuthBundle as their documentation. Everything smoothly configured and running.

After google authentication prompt /connect/google, it redirects to the following URL (blank page)
http://local.xxx.com/app_dev.php/login/check-google?code=4/jUTU2hoQfOiNMUfKJX_bLfCDVoAr.UpnObn7cHC4XOl05ti8ZT3bVT-SeiQI

I'm using FOSUserBundle.

This is my config.yml,

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Techy\VisaBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
       address: x@techy.com
       sender_name: Techy Registration
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled:    true
    from_email:
                address:        xx@techy.tn
                sender_name:    Techy Registration        
    # Facebook configuration
fos_facebook:
  alias:  facebook
  app_id: xx
  secret:  xx
  cookie: true
  permissions: [email, user_hometown, user_location]

services:
        fos_facebook.user.login:
            class: Techy\VisaBundle\Security\User\Provider\FacebookProvider
            arguments:
                facebook: "@fos_facebook.api"
                userManager: "@fos_user.user_manager"
                validator: "@validator"
                container: "@service_container"

        hwi_oauth.user.provider.entity:
              class: HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\OAuthUserProvider
        ib_user.oauth_user_provider:
              class: Techy\VisaBundle\Security\User\Provider\OAuthProvider
              arguments: [@session, @doctrine, @service_container]         
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_name: main
    resource_owners:
        google:
            type: google
            client_id:  xx.apps.googleusercontent.com
            client_secret: xxxxxxx
            scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"



    fosub:
        username_iterations: 5
        properties:
            google: googleId
```

Security.yml

```
    chainprovider:
              chain:
                  providers: [fos_userbundle, fos_facebook_provider,my_custom_hwi_provider]

    fos_userbundle:
      id: fos_user.user_manager
    fos_facebook_provider: 
       id:  fos_facebook.user.login

    my_custom_hwi_provider:
        id: ib_user.oauth_user_provider    
firewalls:

    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/secured
        #anonymous: ~
        http_basic:
            realm: "Secured Area"
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        fos_facebook:
          app_url: "http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=xx"
          server_url: "http://xx.com/app_dev.php/"
          login_path: fos_user_security_login
          check_path: _security_check
          provider: fos_facebook_provider
          default_target_path: /

        form_login:
              provider: fos_userbundle
              login_path: fos_user_security_login
              check_path: fos_user_security_check
              default_target_path: /
              csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
              failure_path:   null

        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                google: "/login/check-google"
            login_path: /login
            failure_path: /login
            oauth_user_provider:
                service: ib_user.oauth_user_provider


        anonymous: true
        logout:    true
        remember_me:
              key:      mySuperDuperKey
              lifetime: 45146
              path:     /
              domain:   ~




access_control:
    #- { path: ^/admin, roles:  IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 134.6.2.8}
    - { path: ^/admin, roles:  [ROLE_ADMIN], ip: 127.0.0.1 }

    #- { path: ^/_internal/secure, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/user/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/secured, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/ad, role: ROLE_USER }

    - { path: ^/edit, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/admin/home, role: ROLE_ADMIN}
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

routing.yml

```
my_user_management:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"



_security_login:
      pattern:   /login

_security_check:
     pattern:  /loginfb
     defaults: { _controller: TechyVisaBundle:User:loginFb }

_security_logout:
      pattern:  /logout


fos_facebook_channel:
    resource: "@FOSFacebookBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"

user_couple_fb_with_account:
    pattern: /user/couple/facebook
    defaults: { _controller: TechyVisaBundle:User:connectFacebookWithAccount }



hwi_oauth_login:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix:   /login
hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

google_login:
    pattern: /login/check-google

#login:
#    pattern:   /login
#    defaults:  { _controller: hh:Security:login }
#login_check:
#    pattern:   /login_check
#
logout:
    path:   /logout
```

Comment: Is the url available only on your machine or to the internet?

Comment: i work on local, but with facebook it works well

Comment: In your local access logs do you have the request from google after you login? If not is because is not reaching your url. If that is the case you need to test it in a "public domain".

Comment: its reached but it stills empty and the Logged in as not changed to my username

Comment: For Google live url is required. It won't work in local environment.